# arduino example for cmd_vel subsriber

Tags: arduino, rosserial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to write an arduino code for subscribing to cmd_vel topic....I am using Mega1280 .....Can anybody tell me or guide me to the link where I can get the idea of subscribing to cmd_vel and rotating my motors??

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/42901/arduino-example-for-cmd_vel-subsriber/) by [jontromanab](https://answers.ros.org/users/2662/jontromanab/) on ROS Answers with karma: 56 on 2012-09-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosserial/Tutorials

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2012-09-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2